# How to correctly escape URI paths in Java when getting them from `getPath`

Tags: java, uri, urlencode

It seems one can not just go from an `URI` to `getPath` and back:

```scala
val f = new java.io.File("/data/projects/Aleatorium/tmp[1]/impact1.aif")
val u = f.toURI
val v = new java.net.URI(u.getScheme, u.getPath, null)
```

this results in the last line throwing

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 34: file:/data/projects/Aleatorium/tmp[1]/impact1.aif
```

So while `u.toString` contains `tmp%5B1%5D`, `u.getPath` decodes to `tmp[1]`. What's the best way to re-encode the path before passing it to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the implementation of `File#toURI`, seems I should use a different constructor, instead of passing `ssp` (scheme specific part), should use one that separates `host` and `path`:

```scala
val v = new java.net.URI(u.getScheme, u.getHost /* ! */, u.getPath, null)
```